# Анимированная SVG маска, которая осветляет фон

Tags: javascript, html, css3, svg, анимация

Нужен следующий анимационный эффект:

Загрузилась HTML-страничка с каким-то фоном, пусть темно-синим.
Спустя 1с сверху-вниз соскальзывает SVG-изображение к центру экрана, которое только осветляет существующий фон (действует как маска).

Должно выглядеть примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать, или хоть намекните куда копать.
Если без Javascript - будет вообще супер!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В качестве SVG изображения, которое будет опускаться сверху-вниз до середины экрана, я выбрал логотип `Adobe`

1. движение логотипа через 1.5 секунды после загрузки страницы:
   `animation:adobe 2s forwards 1.5s;`

Анимация и осветление фона с помощью маски SVG сделано по отредактированному примеру в вопросе.
Добавил ещё переход по ссылке на логотипе.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

.header {
  background: #FFDD00;
  height: 50px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:24px;
  color:#151515;
  padding-top:0.5em;
  z-index:1;
}


.sidebar {
  width: 15%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #5677FC;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:24px;
  color:white;
}

.content {
  background-color: #3B3A75;
  font-size:24px;
  color:white;
  height: 100%;
  padding:1em;
  position:relative;
 
}

.adobe {
width:300px;
position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top:-115%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  animation:adobe 2s forwards 1.5s;
}

@keyframes adobe {
100%{top:40%;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
     <div class="adobe">
       <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">        
       <svg  viewBox="0 0 105 93" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        <mask id="msk">
            <rect  width="420" height="372" fill="white" />
          <path fill-rule="nonzero" d='M66,0h39v93zM38,0h-38v93zM52,35l25,58h-16l-8-18h-18z' fill='black'/>
        </mask> 
            <rect  width="420" height="372" fill="#6260B7" />        
             <rect mask="url(#msk)" x="0"  width="420" height="372" fill="#3B3A75" />
</svg> 
 </a>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но это не совсем-то, что нужно! Маска не так работает - она осветляет/затемняет там, где в маске есть непрозрачные на 100% участки. В приведенном пример - все наоборот. Сейчас подредактирую вопрос, чтобы визуально это продемонстрировать.

Comment: @Majestio Спасибо. Ну примерно понял, что вы хотите. Попробую сделать. Просьба более оперативно реагировать.

Comment: Хорошо, я постараюсь.

Comment: @ Alexandr_TT - и вдогонку ... никаких скроллов от эффекта. Это недопустимо.

Comment: @Majestio Ответ переработан

Comment: Супер! Спасибо! Есть еще просьба - сделать так чтобы съезжающая картинка на вызывала скролла.

Comment: @Majestio Объясни подробней. Что ты имеешь ввиду. У меня скролла нет в полноэкранном режиме. Когда у тебя появляется скролл?

Comment: Нажимаю "Выполнить код" - открывается окошко, соскальзывает картинка и когда она уже почти закончила движение - появляется вертикальный скролл-бар справа. Я понимаю, что пример тестовый. Но если мне придется на сайте использовать огромную картинку, которая по ширине и высоте больше размера окна? Нужно чтобы картинка, которая выступает за пределы окна просто визуально обрезалась, чтобы не затрагивала геометрию внешнего контейнера, ну или всего body

Comment: Примерно как поступает свойство background-size: cover

Comment: @Majestio Хорошо, попробую что-нибудь придумать. Но уже отдельным ответом, так как ты постоянно усложняешь вопрос по сравнению с первоначальным вопросом. Согласен?

Comment: Скорее недостаточно детально задал вопрос)

Comment: @Majestio Ничего страшного :) Просто нужно помнить, что чётко заданный вопрос это уже половина для правильного ответа и экономит время для отвечающего.

Answer (score 2):

javascript для того что бы svg было всегда на 100% экрана - может быть я перемудрил но смотрите, любое значение можно менять

Вот здесь чуть получше: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/OJxZEMN

```js
let body = document.querySelector("body");
let w = body.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let h = body.getBoundingClientRect().height;

svg.setAttribute("width", w + "px");
svg.setAttribute("height", h + "px");

window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
  svg.setAttribute("width", w + "px");
  svg.setAttribute("height", h + "px");
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
.parent {
  height: 100%;
}

.parent,
#svg {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

svg {
  z-index: 100;
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="background">
    <img src="https://catherineasquithgallery.com/uploads/posts/2021-02/1614429316_25-p-temno-sinii-fon-dlya-fotoshopa-29.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="svg">
    <svg id="svg">
      <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#000" fill-opacity="0.8">
        <animate attributeName="height" repeatCount="1" begin="1s" values="100%; 50%"dur="1s" />
        <animate attributeName="y"  repeatCount="1" begin="1s" values="0%; 50%" dur="1s" fill="freeze"/>
      </rect>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но и у вас, что-то не то. Я пробовал экспериментировать, может не то подставлял. Но после анимации у меня остается изначальный фон, т.е. маска исчезает в конце анимации. Но подход ваш интересный, надо еще позаниматься.

Comment: @Majestio я с Казахстана, у нас митинги и беспорядки в стране (посмотрите новости о том что происходит у нас)  ...интернет с перебоями я не смогу в ближайшее время переделать или доделать

Comment: Да уж ... Скорее бы у вас все успокоилось!

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы не было вертикальной полосы прокрутки при полноэкранном режиме, необходимо у SVG изображения не указывать высоту и ширину, также надо обернуть svg блок в родительский контейнер - `<div class="container">`
, для которого указать `width` и `height` в относительных единицах.
В этом случае svg будет адаптивным и заполнит полностью родительский контейнер.

Если мешают полосы прокрутки в окне сниппета, необходимо указать для родительского контейнера `width:"25vw"` `height:25vh` При открывании на полный экран приложение адаптивно увеличится.
В реальном приложении при указании `width:"100vw"` `height:100vh` для род. контейнера при любом самом большом размере svg оно будет уменьшено до размеров экрана браузера, при уменьшении окна браузера или использовании другого гаджета с меньшим дисплеем, SVG изображение подстроится под размеры этого дисплея.

```css
.container {
  width:25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  background-color: #3B3A75;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> content 
     
       <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg">        
       <svg  viewBox="0 0 105 93" xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'>
        <mask id="msk">
            <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
          <path id="path" fill-rule="nonzero" transform="scale(0.5) translate(52.5 -120.5)" d='M66,0h39v93zM38,0h-38v93zM52,35l25,58h-16l-8-18h-18z' fill='black'>
           
          </path>
        </mask> 
            <rect  width="100%" height="100%" fill="#6260B7" />      
             <rect mask="url(#msk)" x="0"  width="100%" height="100%" fill="#3B3A75" /> 
          <animateTransform xlink:href="#path"
           attributeName="transform"
            type="translate"
            begin="0s" dur="2s"
            values="0 0;0 150"
            fill="freeze"
            additive="sum"
            restart="whenNotActive"/>    
</svg> 
 </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: @Majestio Новый вариант

Comment: Большущее спасибо!!!

Comment: @Majestio Пожалуйста, рад был помочь

Comment: Мощно, а есть такой же, но с перламутровыми пуговицами?